# Prolog equality check fails on simple task

Tags: prolog

Im trying to achieve this:

```
   sum(bookmark(num)),
   bookmark(bookmark(bum)),
   bookmark(bookmark(bookmark(num))).

   sum(bookmark(num), bookmark(bookmark(num)), A).
```

**to return** А =  **bookmark(bookmark(bookmark(num)))** 
Im not close yet, since i fail at the bookmark function as stated below.

```
bookmark(e1, e2) :-
    e1 \= 0, 
    e2 \= 0. 

/*#e1 = element-one, e2 = element-two*/

sum(e1, e2, result) :- 
    bookmark(e1, e2),
    e1 is (1+1),
    e2 is (1+1),
    result = (e1 + e2).
```

Im checking if the bookmark function returns true, then the simple addition will follow. Problem is: if the input for the bookmark function is any two numbers, it returns false.
Example with bookmark(1, 2) - false.
Example with bookmark(0, 0) - false.
Any help why this doesn't work will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Variables start with a capital letter. `is` is arithmetic evaluation. `=` is syntactic equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prolog variables start with an *uppercase*. So `e1` is *not* a variable, but a costant, `E1` is a variable.

```
bookmark(E1, E2) :-
    E1 \= 0, 
    E2 \= 0.

sum(E1, E2, Result) :- 
    bookmark(E1, E2),
    E1 is (1+1),
    E2 is (1+1),
    Result = E1 + E2.
```

The above will however only succeed if `E1` and `E2` are both `2`, and then `Result` will be `2 + 2` (not `4`, just `2 + 2`, or in canonical form `+(2, 2)`).

Comment: I forgot about the uppercase (new to prolog). How can i make E1 = E1+1 return just the increased with one atom E1?

Comment: @TomRetterath: you can not update a variable: once a variable is set, you can not change its value. If you backtrack, you undo an assignment. But you do not backtrack explicitly. You can evaluate `Result is E1 + E2.` to evaluate the two values.

Comment: Great! How would i assign the simple addition of those variables into one that hasn't been set yet as a atom? Perhaps with just write?

Comment: @TomRetterath No, you just use `X is (some expression that must be evaluated)` or `X = something like a number or a structure`. If `X` is still "fresh", it is "set to" the right-hand side. If `X` has already been set to something, the Prolog processor will check whether that something matches whatever is on the right-hand side and proceed if this works out. I recommend trying this on the command line or on [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/).